# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to Object[]

Tags: java

I need to implement the code in below but i have problem with

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to Object[] for Object[] nearestPoint = kdtree.nearest(point.toDouble(), 2);
```

in a code below

```
public int getNearestNeighbour(Point point) {
    int result = 0;
    try {
        Object[] nearestPoint = kdtree.nearest(point.toDouble(), 2);
        result = (Integer)nearestPoint[1];
    } catch(Exception e) {
        debug(e);
        result = -1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is `kdtree`? Where is the method `nearest`?

Comment: `nearest` returns a `List`. Don't expect an `Object[]`.

Comment: KDtree is an execution JAR file that include the nearest method to return the nearest point for a given point. i try many cast to convert from list to Object but it doesn't work... please advise me

Comment: @user3166301 Because you can't case a list to an object. Check out the list API for your answer; it's generally best to start there when you're not sure what you can do with an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you code to the following:

```
Object[] nearestPoint = kdtree.nearest(point.toDouble(), 2).toArray();
```

That should convert the `List` that is returned to an `Array` of `Objects`.  [See APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty much explains itself. It looks like kdtree.nearest() returns a List, but you're trying to store it in an array variable. You either need to change the type of the variable or convert from a List to an array.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
    Object[] nearestPoint = kdtree.nearest(point.toDouble(), 2);
    result = (Integer)nearestPoint[1];
```

to

```
    List nearestPoint = kdtree.nearest(point.toDouble(), 2);
    result = (Integer)nearestPoint.get(1); //may be 0 (check he length of list before)
```